# Define functions expression - Clarity Smart contract Stacks

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

The expressions that define functions take one expression for the function body.

[The function body is what is executed when the function is called.]

If the body is limited to one expression only, then how can you create more complex functions that require multiple expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `begin` function for this. It allows you to pass in multiple expressions as a single expression to the body.

https://docs.stacks.co/docs/clarity/language-functions#begin